Page breaks while replying in Nested Comments
I'm creating a Nested Comments app in React. While adding comment in the parent node works fine but, replying to that same node breaks the page. The children nodes doesn't work fine. Here's the explanation of the code below.
Comment.js
const onAddComment = () => {
    if (editMode) {
      handleEditMode(comments.id, inputRef?.current?.innerText);
    } else {
      console.log("DATA HERE", comments.id, input);
      setExpand(true);
      handleInsertNode(comments.id, input); <-- this function breaks the page
      setShowInput(false);
      setInput("");
    }
  };

return (
...
<Action type="REPLY PARENT" handleClick={onAddComment} />
...
)

App.js
const [commentsData, setCommentsData] = useState(comments);
const { insertNode, editNode, deleteNode } = useNode(); <-- this is custom hook created

const handleInsertNode = async (commentId, comment) => {
    console.log("HandleInsertNode Func", commentsData);
    const finalTree = await insertNode(commentsData, commentId, comment);
    setCommentsData(finalTree);
  };

useNode
const insertNode = (tree, commentId, item) => {
    if (tree.id === commentId) {
      tree?.items?.push({
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        name: item,
        items: [],
      });
      return tree;
    }

    let latestNode = [];
    latestNode = tree?.items?.map((newItems) => {
      return insertNode(newItems, commentId, item);
    });

    return { ...tree, items: latestNode };
  };


Although thouroughly tested, but, still error persists. The 'REPLY PARENT' button works exactly like 'COMMENT' button, but, while clicking on it throws error as 'handleInsertNode is not a function and has same common onAddComment function'. What could be the obvious error, which I'm unable to detect. Here's the link to sandbox --> https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nested-comments-app-52jdsh

Share the exact error (copy/paste). Also, Sandbox link doesn't work.

Now sandbox link works... it was private by default

The problem is that you're not declaring an expected prop handleInsertNode in the Comment.js file in the return(), where you render each comment in the comments list
{comments?.items?.map((data) => {
        return <Comment key={data.id} comments={data} />;
      })}

should be
{comments?.items?.map((data) => {
        return <Comment
                  key={data.id}
                  comments={data}
                  handleInsertNode={props.handleInsertNode}
                  /* insert other default props here */
                />;
      })}

Think about the fact that this comment instance is a reply node and we're not able to add a reply to the first reply and i think you'll have a good mental map of the problem.
